# How to create and open a file in C and make it avaliable to the entire program?

Tags: c, file

I want to create a log file for a program, for that I want to create and open a `.txt` file and make it available to the entire program for writing into it.

For example, I have a global file pointer `fp`, which has created in a file "debug.c". Now I opened the file using a function:

```
void initlog()
   {
      fp = fopen("filename.txt","w");
   }
```

If I open the file using above function Is it possible to write/append  to the same file, in other parts of the program?

Can I share the `fp` using `extern` keyword with other files,and is it possible to get the opened file pointer(`fp`) in other files by this?

### EDIT

Can't use threads since it a single threaded program

Comment: If you dont use threads i see no problem in this.

Comment: Yes. But it's arguably better not to do it that way. Instead implement a logging facility which exports APIs to write to the log. Other parts of the program would then call the APIs rather than writing to the file directly.

Comment: @AlanAu What do you mean by the logging facility?? If I want to write to the log then also I need an opened file pointer , so I have to open and close the file often, In order to avoid that Can I open the File for the first time and make the opened file pointer global, then Can I write to the file when I needed and close the file at the end of the log ?, So that I can avoid frequent open and closing of the file..

Comment: No you don't need to give the fp to everyone. Implement `initlog` and an additional `wrtitelog` function inside debug.c. Only those functions need the fp. Everywhere else just calls `writelog`. That's just a simple example. A real logging facility would do more (eg different levels of logging). This is just standard modular design. So if you want to change the logging later (eg write to console instead) then only the internal logging implementation needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
freopen("file.txt","w",stdout);
```

This will let your printf write in the file.

To append use "a" instead of "w".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a global file pointer you could capsule the logging in a call

e.g.

```
void Log(const char* frmt, ... )
{
  FILE* fp = fopen("yourlog.txt","ab" );
  if (fp != NULL)
  {
   va_list args;
   va_start(args, frmt);
   vfprintf(fp, frmt, args);
   va_end(args);
   fclose(fp);
  } 
}
```

The advantage is that it is flushed to the disk even when your program crashes. You can also decide on a special format for the output e.g. adding timestamp etc.

The disadvantage it may give a lot of file I/O or performance loss, depends on your use case